# matrix duplicate element check with recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 6], [7, 8, 1]]
```

I need a recursive function in python to check the matrix element duplicate. The function should return true if "L" has a row with no duplicate of the same element and false otherwise.

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you facing issues?

Comment: I don't think this needs a recursive function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an academic exercise. No recursion needed.

```
lst = [
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 6], [7, 8, 1]],
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 8, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
[[1, 2, 3]]
]

for ll in lst:
   r = len([x for i,x in enumerate(ll) if [1 for y in ll if len(set(x)&set(y))].count(1) > 1]) == 0
   print(r, ll)
```

Output

```
False [[1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 6], [7, 8, 1]]
True  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
False [[1, 2, 3], [4, 8, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
True  [[1, 2, 3]]
```

--- Recursive version ---

```
lst = [
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 6], [7, 8, 1]],
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 8, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
[[1, 2, 3]]
]

def chkdup(lst):
   if len(lst) == 1: return True # one list always true
   for ls in lst[1:]: # compare other lists
      if len(set(lst[0]) & set(ls)): return False # dups found
   return chkdup(lst[1:]) # recursion, process next list
       
for ll in lst:  # each list in test data
   print(chkdup(ll), ll)
```

Output

```
False [[1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 6], [7, 8, 1]]
True  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
False [[1, 2, 3], [4, 8, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
True  [[1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is ugly, bulky and needs refactoring, but here you go: (*It is recursive, but recursion seems unnecessary.)

```
def evaluate_matrix(matrix):
    def has_duplicate(arr):
        for item in arr:
            if arr.count(item) >= 2:
                return True
        return False
    #Here is where all that recursion stuff happens
    if len(matrix) <= 1:
        return has_duplicate(matrix[0])
    else:
        return bool(has_duplicate(matrix[0]) + evaluate_matrix(matrix[1:]))
    


is_double = [[1,2,3,4], [1,1,3,4]]
is_not_double = [5,6,7,8], [[9,10,11,12]]

print("Matrix is_double has a duplicate: ", evaluate_matrix(is_double))
print("Matrix is_not_double has a duplicate: ", evaluate_matrix(is_not_double))
```

Comment: not working, when I give any matrix it gives "false"